# How to get size of an inner hash in nested hash in perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I have following hash of hash :

```
%tgs = (
'articles' =>  {
                   'vim' => '20 awesome articles posted',
                   'awk' => '9 awesome articles posted',
                   'sed' => '10 awesome articles posted'
               },
'ebooks'   =>  {
                   'linux 101'    => 'Practical',
                   'nagios core'  => 'Monitor'
               }
);
```

I am using following :

```
$size = scalar keys (%{tgs{'articles'}});
```

but it isn't working .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `$size = scalar keys (%{$tgs{'articles'}});` should do the trick - you forgot the $ sigil.

Where `my $size = keys %{ $tgs{articles} };` is more idiomatic perl.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the dollar sign:

```
my $size = scalar keys %{ $tgs{articles} };
```